# Installed app doesn't show on installed applications lens (Ubuntu 12.04 dash)

Tags: 12.04, applications-lens

Recently, I installed the software sources app on my 12.04 LTS but it doesn't show on the installed applications (applications lens). It shows on /usr/share/applications. What needs to be done so that the Software Sources icon appear on the application lens? Thanks.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Software Sources
GenericName=Software Sources
Comment=Configure the sources for installable software and updates
Exec=software-properties-gtk
Icon=software-properties
Terminal=false
NoDisplay=true
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;X-GNOME-SystemSettings;
MimeType=text/x-apt-sources-list;
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=software-properties
```

Comment: Can you please post the contents of the corresponding .desktop file located at /usr/share/applications ?

Comment: [Desktop Entry]
Name=Software Sources
GenericName=Software Sources
Comment=Configure the sources for installable software and updates
Exec=software-properties-gtk
Icon=software-properties
Terminal=false
NoDisplay=true
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;X-GNOME-SystemSettings;
MimeType=text/x-apt-sources-list;
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=software-properties

Comment: Edit your answer, do not post it as comment.

Comment: hakermania:
I just supplied the information you requested above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained here on [Standard Keys - Desktop Entry Specifications](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#key-nodisplay),

> `NoDisplay` means "this application exists, but don't display it in the menus"

The `NoDisplay` field is causing this desktop shortcut not to show up in menus.

This, of course, was done deliberately by the developers of the application. However, if you wish to see this application in menus, just completely remove the `NoDisplay` field:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Software Sources
GenericName=Software Sources
Comment=Configure the sources for installable software and updates
Exec=software-properties-gtk
Icon=software-properties
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;X-GNOME-SystemSettings;
MimeType=text/x-apt-sources-list;
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=software-properties
```